# Migrate model object on save in Django

Tags: django, django-models, archive

I want to create two models in Django

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    delete = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def save(self, *args, **args):
        if self.delete():
            # move object to Post Archive

class BlogPostArchive(BlogPost):
    date_deleted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How would I define the method to migrate the BlogPost object that needs to be deleted into the archive?

Comment: Is that possible just simply create a new archive instance while you are deleting a post instance?

Comment: Yeah, and if I want to add an undelete field, it migrates the archive object back to the blogpost

Comment: what do you mean "undelete field"?

Comment: It is moved from the archive model to the blog post model